# ODBC data tracing

Tags: sql, odbc, trace

I need to see every row  of data, which  program is receiving through ODBC driver (after select query).

I have tried to use ODBC tracing utility, which comes with windows xp, but it doesn't show content of each row.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have source then you can save result of the `SQLGetData()`.

Without sources you can analyze network activity. For example if you want to see how Oracle ODBC driver exchange information with server you can use Wireshark and apply filter:

```
 tcp.port==1521
```